# How do I retrieve all submitted fields in an onsubmit handler?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get all submitted names and values inside an `onsubmit` function without using `document.getElementsByName`, `document.getElementById` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is a bit vague, but to at least answer your question one way, as long as an `onsubmit` is being performed on a `form` you can get the fields and values back in a serialized form.

#### JS:

```
$("form").onsubmit(function(){
    var serialized = $(this).serialize();

    alert(serialized);

    return false;
});
```